# Avoid textNode creation after new line?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, textnode

If I manually write those following lines in an HTML file:

```
<div>
<input type="button" value="Button 1">
<input type="button" value="Button 2">
</div>
```

A text node will be created for each new line.

I wanted to understand the useCapture argument of addEventListener method.
I choosed to access DOM elements using childNodes property of my div element but I will have to ignore textNodes between elements. This isn't really practical:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){alert(1);}, true);

document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].childNodes[1].addEventListener("click", function(){alert(2);}, false);

document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0].childNodes[3].addEventListener("click", function(){alert(3);}, false);
```

Here you see that I have to ignore `childNodes[0]` and `childNodes[2]` in order to select my 2 input tags.

Is there a way to bypass textNodes creation without writing all HTML code just on one line and without using Javascript `createElement`?

Is it possible to write HTML code without creating textNodes when going to new line?

Comment: Is it possible in `javascript` to write two lines of code inside an `if` without `{ }` ? No, this is how the language was designed and works. same thing here.

Comment: @gdoron in Javascript, C, C++, C#, {} is always needed when we have more than two lines of code

Comment: htI know... I meant to say, this is the HTML syntax rules just like javascript, HTML has it's rules, and new line creates a textNode... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, *don't repeat yourself* !  You're repeating the same DOM query over and over.

Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
div.addEventListener("click", function(){alert(1);}, true);

var buttons = div.getElementsByTagName("button");  
buttons[0].addEventListener("click", function(){alert(2);}, false);
buttons[1].addEventListener("click", function(){alert(2);}, false);
```

calling `getElementsByTagName` to get the buttons trivially skips the text nodes - problem solved!

Comment: Ok, it's just 3 lines of example but it's maybe better to put in a variable.
I didn't want to directly access buttons because I had other buttons before and using childNodes is nice to access div's buttons

Comment: @baptx `childNodes` is clearly _not_ nice, for exactly the reason you've found.  If you're only interested in elements, _ask the DOM to give you those elements!_

Comment: You're right, it could be nice but due to this textNodes it's not :/

Comment: @baptx yup, but the text nodes can't be avoided unless you strip the newlines from the content before it's sent to the browser.

Comment: It has to be send as one line of code by the server to avoid textNodes, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I will use childNodes for dynamically created elements only

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to write HTML code without creating textNodes when going to new line?

**Nope.**

Unless you parse the HTML file before sending it to the client, which I guess that solution isn't what you're after...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry. Only possibility is generate HTML code using programming language such as PHP, RUBY and add something like this.

```
<input type="button" value="Button 1"><%-
%><input type="button" value="Button 2">
```

But I guess it's not answer you want hear.

Comment: I've tried parsing some lines with PHP following this link:
http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php
If textNodes are removed using <%- %> it with serialize everything to one line of code by the way.
So I think we can't get an output human-readable directly in page source (except Firebug or any DOM inspector) without having textNodes after page request.

Comment: My example is for Ruby on Rails in schema file.html.erb